# Android SQLite Query and using cursor to deal with multiple rows

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursor

I've got a query, (I'm using `rawQuery()`)

```
  SELECT * FROM <table>
```

I'm then storing what it returns using a cursor. From their what I want to do is, start at the first row so.. `cursor.moveToFirst()` then take each column , column by column and store its particular value in a variable. I then want to move onto the next row and do the same. So I guess my question is How would I get cursor to deal with multiple columns?

Thanks,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I might be missing something here, wouldn't you have a nested loop.

The outer loop cycles through each records:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
  ...
  // inner loop here
  ...
}
```

and the inner loop would cycle through each column

```
for (i=0; i<cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
  ...
  String var1 = cursor.getString(i);
  ...
}
```

Comment: I know this is already accepted, but a `do {}while (cursor.moveToNext());` works better, because if you check .moveToNext first, you skip the first record... Learned from experience...

Comment: Are you sure? A cursor typically is sitting at position -1 when returned and calling moveToNext() will move it to the first row.
Also, with your logic the code block inside do{} will always execute at least once, even if the Cursor contains no records.